# Extract numbers if string format matches

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check if an input string follows a pattern and if it does extract information from it.

My pattern is like this `Episode 000 (Season 00)`. The 00s are numbers that can range from 0-9. Now I want to check if this input `Episode 094 (Season 02)` matches this pattern and because it does it should then extract those two numbers, so I end up with two integer variables `94` & `2`:

```
string latestFile = "Episode 094 (Season 02)";
if (!Regex.IsMatch(latestFile, @"^(Episode)\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]\s\((Season)\s[0-9][0-9]\)$"))
    return

int Episode = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(latestFile, @"\d+").Value);
int Season = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(latestFile, @"\d+").Value);
```

The first part where I check if the overall string matches the pattern works, but I think it can be improved. For the second part, where I actually extract the numbers I'm stuck and what I posted above obviously doesn't works, because it grabs all digits from the string. So if anyone of you could help me figure out how to only extract the three number characters after `Episode` and the two characters after `Season` that would be great.

Comment: What if I told you there were shows with [more than 10,000 episodes?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_television_programs_by_episode_count) In that list there is also a show with over 100 seasons (TV Slagalica, a Serbian game show, which as of posting has 104 seasons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^Episode (\d{1,3}) \(Season (\d{1,2})\)$
```

Captures the 2 numbers (even with length 1 to 3/2) and gives them back as a group.
You can go even further and name your groups:

```
^Episode (?<episode>\d{1,3}) \(Season (?<season>\d{1,2})\)$
```

and then call them.

Example for using groups:

```
string pattern = @"abc(?<firstGroup>\d{1,3})abc";
string input = "abc234abc";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = rgx.Match(input);
string result = match.Groups["firstGroup"].Value; //=> 234
```

You can see what the expressions mean and test them [here](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 2):

In your regex `^(Episode)\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]\s\((Season)\s[0-9][0-9]\)$` you are capturing `Episode` and `Season` in a capturing group, but what you actually want to capture is the digits. You could switch your capturing groups like this:

[`^Episode\s([0-9][0-9][0-9])\s\(Season\s([0-9][0-9])\)$`](https://regex101.com/r/AotmAu/1)

Matching 3 digits in this way `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` can be written as `\d{3}` and `[0-9][0-9]` as `\d{2}`.

That would look like [`^Episode\s(\d{3})\s\(Season\s(\d{2})\)$`](https://regex101.com/r/AotmAu/2)

To match one or more digits you could use `\d+`.

The `\s` is a matches a [whitespace character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html). You could use `\s` or a whitespace.

Your regex could look like:

[`^Episode (\d{3}) \(Season (\d{2})\)$`](https://regex101.com/r/ICeS83/2)

```
string latestFile = "Episode 094 (Season 02)";
GroupCollection groups = Regex.Match(latestFile, @"^Episode (\d{3}) \(Season (\d{2})\)$").Groups;
int Episode = Int32.Parse(groups[1].Value);
int Season = Int32.Parse(groups[2].Value);
Console.WriteLine(Episode);
Console.WriteLine(Season);
```

That would result in:

```
94
2
```

[Demo C#](http://rextester.com/LDWRX89822)

Comment: and if you want to make sure that you always have 3 digits for episode and 2 digits for season you can change it to `^Episode (\d{3}) \(Season (\d{2})\)$`

Comment: @msokrates That is correct. I have updated my answer.